# The code shows error in the recv statement while using mpi4py

Tags: python, mpi, hpc, mpi4py

I have a written a code to calculate integration using mpi4py, the code runs perfectly when it is hard-coded i.e the inputs are defined beforehand but as soon as I take inputs from user there seems to be an error in the Recv() function. The code I have written is

```
from mpi4py import MPI

def fx(x):
    return x*x

def Trap(local_a , local_b, local_n, h):
    integral = (fx(local_a) + fx(local_b))/2.0
    x = local_a
    for i in range(1,int(local_n)):
        x += h
        integral += fx(x)
    integral *= h
    return integral


comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank=comm.rank
size=comm.size
source = 1
dest = 0
a = 0.0
b = 0.0
n = 0

if rank == 0:

    a = float(input("Enter Upper Limit \n"))
    b = float(input("Enter Lower Limit \n"))
    n = int(input("Enter number of trapezoids \n"))
    for i in range(1,size):
        dest += 1
        comm.send(a, dest, tag = 0)
        comm.send(b, dest, tag = 1)
        comm.send(n, dest, tag = 2)

else:
    a=comm.recv(source = 0, tag = 0)
    b=comm.recv(source = 0, tag = 1)
    n=comm.recv(source = 0, tag = 2)

h = (b-a)/n
local_n = n/size
local_a = a + rank * local_n * h
local_b = (local_a + local_n) * h

integral = Trap(local_a, local_b, local_n, h)

if rank == 0:
    total = integral
    while (source < size):
        source += 1
        integral = comm.recv(source,tag = 0)
        total = total + integral
        
else:
    comm.send(integral, dest = 0, tag = 0)

if rank == 0:
    print(" With n = %d trapezoids, our estimate \n" %(n))
    print("of the integral from %f to %f = %0.8f\n" %(a,b,total))
```

The error it shows while running is

```
integrationmpi.py:52: UserWarning: the 'buf' argument is deprecated
  integral = comm.recv(source,tag = 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "integrationmpi.py", line 52, in <module>
    integral = comm.recv(source,tag = 0)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1438, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.recv
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 339, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_recv
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 277, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_recv_obarg
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
```

What is the problem here, I don't understand!!

Comment: note your program only works with 2 MPI tasks. use `MPI_Bcast()` in order to use any number of tasks.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet shouldn't it automatically go to other processes too as the else statement does not have any condition, its either rank =0 or else it will run?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I edited the code to this, there are no errors but I am not getting the correct value of integration 
` if rank == 0:
    total = integral
    while (source < size):
        source += 1
        total = total + integral
        
        
else:
    comm.bcast(integral, root = 0)`

Comment: my bad, I missed the `for` loop. As an other matter of style, consider using `MPI_Reduce()` to sum the partial integrals.

Comment: `source` is initialized with `1`, but you first `source += 1`, and then `comm.recv(source, ...)`. Fix `source` and then `comm.recv(source = source, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `source` must be a keyword argument in `Comm.recv`. If you look at [the documentation](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/mpi4py.MPI.Comm.html#mpi4py.MPI.Comm.recv), you'll see this:

> recv(buf=None, source=ANY_SOURCE, tag=ANY_TAG, status=None)

When you call it like you currently do:

```py
integral = comm.recv(source,tag = 0)
```

the value of `source` is instead passed in the `buf` argument and MPI is trying to receive a double object into a smaller buffer, hence the truncation error. It also results in a deprecation warning:

```
integrationmpi.py:52: UserWarning: the 'buf' argument is deprecated
  integral = comm.recv(source,tag = 0)
```

Either call it like you do in all other places with a keyword argument `comm.recv(source = source, tag = 0)` or explicitly pass `None` as the first non-keyword argument.

Comment: It shows this error now that the rank is invalid
`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "integrationmpi.py", line 52, in <module>
    integral = comm.recv(source = source,tag = 0)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1438, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.recv
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 341, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_recv
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 299, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_recv_match
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_RANK: invalid rank

`

Comment: That's because you should move `source += 1` **after** the `recv` call in the loop. Right now, in the last iteration, `source` becomes equal to the communicator size and `recv` fails.